# mongo db collections - some do, some don't

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo shell, after running a mapreduce on collection DEPS with output named STATS:

```
>show collections
DEPS
STATS
system.indexes
```

So I see both collections, no problem.  However:

```
>db.DEPS.findOne()    <--  returns a DEPS record
>db.STATS.findOne()   <--  returns err msg "db.stats.findOne is not a function"
```

So to see stats data I need to type:

```
>db.getCollection("STATS").findOne()
```

This is not a problem, in so far as I can see all the data I need to see.  But as a matter of understanding Mongo, why is it that the first collection (created via mongoimport) comes with a findOne method, and the second (created via mapreduce) does not ?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the collection name conflicts with the `db.stats()` command (which gives you database statistics). I'd not have expected case insensitity here, though.

Comment: Thilo  - you nailed it.  I used uppercase STATS in my post above (for readability) but the actual experiment was carried out in lowercase.  After testing again in uppercase everything was fine.  I'm brand new to Mongo and didn't realize lowercase "stats" to be a name already in use.  If you re-post as a stk ovflow answer I'll click accept  - thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. Maybe the collection name conflicts with the db.stats() command (which gives you database statistics). I'd not have expected case insensitity here, though.

Comment: that's it  -  I used lowercase at run time, in fact  -  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem and it really seems to be name conflict. I was wondering how to delete the the "stats" collection and the original question gave the answer:

```
>db.getCollection("stats").drop()
```

Just replace findOne() with drop()

Comment: Same for renaming it : `db.getCollection("stats").renameCollection("newname")`.